# Pydrill Heapmemory Issue while Executing Spark submit commnads

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-drill

**Exception :**

[MainThread  ] [ERROR] : Message   : TransportError(500, '{\n  "errorMessage" : "RESOURCE ERROR: There is not enough heap memory to run this query using the web interface. \n\nPlease try a query with fewer columns or with a filter or limit condition to limit the data returned. \nYou can also try an ODBC/JDBC client. \n\n[Error Id: 8dc824fc-b1b5-4352-85fe-84e2eb5ff71d on

Comment: pls add what you are trying, the command and little more details

Comment: we are using bigdata for backend. and we are executing sql queries by using spark with python.

and in python we are using pydrill to connect to bigdata and get the data here am facing  heap memory issue ...

Comment: The error says "There is not enough heap memory to run this query". Try checking the memroy available for your spark in sparkUI, http://localhost:4040, or your custom url

Comment: actually query will execute multiple times with different input some times it is executing properly and some time it is giving the heap memory issue..

can please tell me how can i increase apache drill heap size memory